# Few questions about /root /home directories and installation location options

Tags: 15.04, storage

So, I'd like to install Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 8.1. I currently have a 120GB SSD and 2TB SSHD. I will be usng Ubuntu for programming, currently only plan on installing Eclipse and MDK3. Now I have 10GB of free space I created on my SSD and 50GB on my SSHD. What I would like to know is, do programs install to the /home directory? Should I give more space to my /home directory or /root directory? Is 6GB enough for my /root directory and 4GB for my /home directory or should I just install both on my SSHD? I plan on using the SSHD for swap-space anyway. Thanks (Ubuntu says 5GB is enough?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me clear some things you seem to have misunderstood:

- `/home` is not your home directory. It contains the home directories of the users of the system.
- `/root` is not the file system root, but the home directory of the system's root user. The file system root is `/`

---

> do programs install to the /home directory?

TL;DR: No.

When installed by the package manager, thy go to various locations in `/usr`, e.g. executables go to `/usr/bin`, libraries to `/usr/lib`, and other stuff, such as resource files would go to `/usr/share`.
When software isn't installed using the package manager, i.e. manually, it follows the same as above, but in `/usr/local`.
Proprietary software, which may not be directly installed from official repos often goes into `/opt`.

Note that settings, cache files, etc. of these programs are stored in your  home directory. Also, not all software follows those standards.

---

> Is 6GB enough for my /root directory and 4GB for my /home directory?

See above: `/root` != `/`.

As you are planning on installing few software, 6GB seems enough for the root partition. I'd say you could even go with less. Much more so if you installed a more lightweight flavor like Lubuntu.

Depending on how much code you are going to write and how much resources such as images etc. you need, I'd say 4GB could be somewhat scarce. Personally, I'd put `/home` on the SSHD and give it somewhat more space, but again, I don't know how you are going to use your system, so this is actually 99% opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks, went with 5GB on my root partition and  5GB with my /home. 16GB of swap on the SSHD. By the time I use the 5GB on either partition/directory I'll probably upgrade to a 240GB SSD.